# javascript/react Syntax error when nothing in useEffect seems to be wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api

When I ran my react code, I get a Syntax error

```
App.jsx:8 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (at App.jsx:8:1)
    at App.jsx:8:1
```

i dont understand why this is wrong if you look at App.jsx:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function App() {

  const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState([{}])

  useEffect( () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api", {mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then(
        res => res.json()
      )
      .then(
        data => {
          setBackendData(data)
        }
      )
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="App">

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There is nothing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `{mode: 'no-cors'}` won't disable CORS errors as you would expect. It tells browser something like: Block my frontend JavaScript code from seeing contents of the response body and headers under all circumstances.

And you probably don't want that. If you have issues with CORS, it can't be fixed on frontend, this is a backend issu, so backend should return more specified headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to be exact)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due a CORS issue with the target server.

To fix that you must include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: domain.com` in your server code or configuration

Answer (score 0):

maybe your API don't return a json, try this

```
 useEffect( () => {
fetch("http://localhost:8000/api", {mode: 'no-cors'})
  .then(result => result.text())
  .then(
    data => {
      setBackendData(data)
    }
      )
  }, [])
```